# How do I correctly use the inverse_transform method when using PowerTransformer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I am having some difficulty using the inverse_transform method to inversely transform an array after performing successive transforms on various arrays. I am able to access the lambda value used for the original transformation using `.lambdas_` attribute. Furthermore, I understand that the code for performing the inverse_transform is listed [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PowerTransformer.html#sklearn.preprocessing.PowerTransformer). However, I would like to know how to use the inverse_transform method properly.

This code does perform the inverse transform as expected:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PowerTransformer

a = np.array([1,3,3,6,3]).reshape(-1, 1)

bc = PowerTransformer(method='box-cox', standardize=False)
bc.fit(a)
a_transformed = bc.transform(a)

a_inverse_transformed = bc.inverse_transform(a_transformed)
a_inverse_transformed
```

The output of this code shows that a is the same as a_inverse_transformed. However, I am not able to store lambdas for later inverse_transform in other scripts or after other transforms. Here is the code I have tried:

```
a = np.array([1,3,3,6,3]).reshape(-1, 1)
bc = PowerTransformer(method='box-cox', standardize=False)
bc.fit(a)
a_transformed = bc.transform(a)
a_lambda = bc.lambdas_[0]

b = np.array([11,33,35,60,38]).reshape(-1, 1)
bc = PowerTransformer(method='box-cox', standardize=False)
bc.fit(b)
b_transformed = bc.transform(b)


bc.set_params(**{'lambdas_':a_lambda})
a_inverse_transformed = bc.inverse_transform(a_transformed)
a_inverse_transformed
```

I get the following error on the above code:

```
ValueError: Invalid parameter lambdas_ for estimator PowerTransformer(copy=True, method='box-cox', standardize=False). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.
```

Also, I have tried finding the correct param by using bc.get_params().keys(). The only keys that I see are

```
dict_keys(['copy', 'method', 'standardize'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you can directly assign the lambda values.
So initially you save the .lambdas_ used for the transformation such as:
savedLamdas = bc.lambdas_

Then later, prior to performing the .inverse_transformed(), you restore the saved lambdas directly, such as:
bc.lambdas_ = savedLamdas

I was surprised that you could set the lambdas_ attribute directly, but it works (at least in my version of scikit-learn 0.21.2).